# Is "by a many" the same thing as "by many"?

Tags: meaning, idioms

I found this on a The Guardian article:

> John ClareJohn Clare was steeped in nature. There is no literary
>   sightseeing here: he writes from inside the landscape. “Young Lambs”
>   could almost be a farmer talking: “The spring is coming by **a many
>   signs**.”

Is "by a many" the same thing as "by many". It looks like the "a" was added for stylistic purpose. Also, is this expression still used or archaic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the point of the poem [*Young Lamb* by John Clare](https://www.poemhunter.com/poem/young-lambs/#content) is to describe spring possibly through the eyes of a farmer.

Since it is a poem the author may take liberties of phrasing and cadence, and it appears to be a presented for *stylistic* reasons.

Answer (score 1):

It's from a poem. Poetry is not subject to rules in the same way that prose is. The article contains quotations from poems about spring. A visual clue, in a prose article, that a poem is being quoted, is the use of slashes to separate the lines:

> Clare writes exactly as he sees: “Lies all his length as dead – and
>   lets me go / Close bye and never stirs but baking lies, / With legs
>   stretched out as though he could not rise”

[The 10 best poems about spring (the Guardian)](https://www.theguardian.com/culture/gallery/2014/mar/21/the-10-best-poems-about-spring)

The whole poem:

> Young Lambs
>
> The spring is coming by a many signs;
>   The trays are up, the hedges
>   broken down,
>   That fenced the haystack, and the remnant shines
>   Like some old antique fragment weathered brown.
>   And where suns peep, in every sheltered place,
>   The little early buttercups unfold
>   A
>   glittering star or two--till many trace
>   The edges of the blackthorn
>   clumps in gold.
>   And then a little lamb bolts up behind
>   The hill
>   and wags his tail to meet the yoe*,
>   And then another, sheltered from
>   the wind,
>   Lies all his length as dead--and lets me go
>   Close bye
>   and never stirs but baking lies,
>   With legs stretched out as though
>   he could not rise.

[Young Lambs by John Clare](http://thewordden.blogspot.com/2016/03/saturday-rave-young-lambs-by-john-clare.html)

- believed to be a Lincolnshire dialect word meaning 'ewe'.

Answer (score -2):

It is certainly not current usage. Whether it was considered current in the 18th century when Clare was writing, I don't know.

Comment: It wasn't really current at the time, but it would have still been *familiar* at that time as approximative *a*, making the following quantity vaguer than it would otherwise be; *a many* now survives only with attributive modifiers (*a great many*, etc.).